# What "topological setting" would make complex analysis fluent?

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, riemann-sphere

In measure theory, the order topology on $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$ (extended real) and $[0,\infty]$ provides rich foundation to analyze measurable functions and abstract integral.

Just like this, i heard that there is a topological setting which makes complex analysis fluent, namely *Riemann Sphere*.

I have proved that the **one point compactification $\mathbb{C}\cup\{\infty\}$ of $\mathbb{C}$** and **2-dimensional sphere $S^2$** are homeomorphic.

I heard that in complex analysis, $\frac{1}{0}$ is defined to be $\infty$ and it is quite useful. THe problem is, the text using in the class does not appeal this point of view. Since i'm quite comfortable with topology and measure theory, i want to study complex analysis with a *deep point of view*.

What else useful topological settings are there to study complex analysis?

Moreover, is there a text written with this aspect?

Comment: Riemann surfaces.